# Obtaining PHP variable from HTML <input>

Tags: php, html, if-statement

This is my first site with PHP and I'm making contact form that sends mail to me using PHP.
I want to set two different messages:

1. First message sends if all fields are filled;
2. Second message sends if one of two specific `input`s (*specific-text-1* and *specific-text-2*) are empty.

**HTML in contact.html**

```html
<form id="query-form" class="query-form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="specific-text-1" placeholder="Text 1">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="specific-text-2" placeholder="Text 2">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Email Subject">
  <br>
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message text" maxlength="700"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Send Message">
</form>
```

**PHP in other file, contact.php**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  // I want $specific1 and $specific2 to be in if command
  $specific1 = $_POST['specific-text-1'];
  $specific2 = $_POST['specific-text-2'];
  $mailTo = "mail@mymail.com";

  $txt = "Message received.\n\nSpecific-text-1: ".$specific1."\n"."Specific-text-2: ".$specific2."\n\n"."Message context: \n\n".$message;
  mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt);
  }
?>
```

instead of `$txt = "Message received..."`, I want to use something like this:

```
if (specific-text-1 == '' || specific-text-2 == '') {
  $txt = "Message2 received.\n\n"."Message context: \n\n".$message;
}
else {
  $txt = "Message received.\n\nSpecific-text-1: ".$specific1."\n"."Specific-text-2: ".$specific2."\n\n"."Message context: \n\n".$message;
}
```

How do I get PHP to know if `specific-text-1` or `specific-text-2` texts that user types are empty and send `Message2` or if are both full send `Message`?

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is backwards.

The code will be simpler if you build `$txt` incrementally with concatenation.

```
$txt = "Message received.\n\n";
if ($specific1 != "" && $specific2 != "") {
    $txt .= "Specific-text-1: $specific1\nSpecific-text-2: $specific2\n\n";
}
$txt .= "Message context:\n\n$message";
```

The `.=` operator appends the string to the variable.

This will add the specific text fields to the mail only if both of them are filled in by the user.

Comment: can I do ```if ($specific1 != "" && $specific 2 != "")```. Also, does it look for user's input on those elements?

Comment: Yes, you could do that instead, if you only want to include them if both are filled in.

Comment: Of course it looks for user input on those elements, that's what `$_POST` contains.

Comment: I tried with what you anwered me, with ````if ($specific1 != "" && $specific2 != "") {
    $txt .= "Specific-text-1: $specific1\nSpecific-text-2: $specific2\n\n";
}````, also tried with ````else```` but message in my inbox is still 2nd one. What am I missing?

Comment: You're saying that you got the message with `Specific-text-1:` even though you didn't fill in both specific text fields?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried with ````||````. I need either of these to be empty. Also tried with ````&&```` and emptied both of them, but still 2nd message. Do you want me to post full code on JSFiddle? Sorry for long conversation, cannot move to chat yet

Comment: Maybe you haven't described your logic clearly. When should it send the long message, when should it send the short message?

Comment: jsfiddle isn't useful, this is PHP, not JavaScript.

Comment: I've uploaded full code in here. https://www.codepile.net/pile/K5DjOeg6 . Note: $order and $address are $specific1 and 2

Comment: You're missing the `.` in `$txt .=`.

Comment: So you're replacing `$txt` instead of appending to it.

Comment: added ````$txt .=````, still same. even when both are empty, it shows other, longer, message

Comment: And you have the logic backwards. When you check that `$order` and `$address` are not empty you should add those to the text. You're using those variables outside the `if`, even though they may be empty.

Comment: Sorry if i've been not clear. I want to, if they are empty, to make a report a bug contact that doesn't require their order ID. But, if they aren't empty ( means that they entered order ID) then it should be type like a query ( product not working ). That's why I use ````$order```` and ````$address```` in ````else```` command

Comment: That's what my code does. The `if` block runs when they're not empty, and adds them to the text. Your code adds them to the text unconditionally.

Comment: I'm really sorry. Whole time, I was thinking that ````!=```` mean that they ARE empty. My bad. Thank you. My host is down, cannot check the code right now.

Comment: You could use the `empty()` function if it's more understandable. `if (!empty($order) && !empty($address))`

Comment: Yup, I got it now. Thank you for your patience very much! Good night.